# Run-time error '6': Overflow when variable declared as Long

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet where I loop through all the stocks for one year and output:

- The ticker symbol
- Yearly change (didn't get there yet).
- The percentage change (didn't get there yet).
- The total stock volume of the stock.

The script gets the total volume for the first few tickers but doesn't run further.

Worksheet with unique tickers in "I" column and not complete Total Volume in "L" column:
[image]

I get

> Run-time error '6': Overflow

I changed my data type from Integer to Long and it didn't help.

Script with line of the code highlighted by debugger:
[image]

Comment: Could you please post the code instead of the picture?

Comment: Are you using `Option Explicit` ?  Not all your variables are declared.

Comment: At that point, what is the value of `Cells(current_row, 7).value)` ?

Comment: `Long` isn't long enough, you'll need `LongLong`  - or floating-point numbers (`Double`).

Comment: Great, thank you @CherryDT! I used Double and it worked. I tried LongLong and it works as well.

Answer (score 2):

Long will support values up to 2147483647, and the value you have for AAB (cell L3) already comes dangerously close to that. You should probably consider using a data type that will allow for larger values. See VBA datatypes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary)

Comment: Great, thank you! I used Double and it worked. I tried LongLong and it works as well.